# Elixir Ecto - DNS Resolution

Tags: dns, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, amazon-aurora

We have a Phoenix App that is connecting to an AWS Aurora RDS instance for the database. However, we are using the DNS string (e.g. `company.cluster-sdfssfd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`) which is dynamic. Last night we noticed that the underlying ips were rotated by AWS, however, our app did not pick up on these changes and was trying to write to the old dns mapped host which was now a read-only replica. How can we get Phoenix/Ecto to automatically refresh the DNS?

Comment: After how long did it connect to the new IP? Might `cache_refresh` here: http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/inet_cfg.html be relevant?

Comment: It never did, I had to restart the app and then it connected immediately.

Comment: Did you restart it within 1 hour of this incident? (`cache_refresh` defaults to 1 hour.)

Comment: I guess the best idea is to use static proxy for database, which would have always same IP and would point to the real dynamic address.

Comment: @Dogbert I restarted about 12 hours later then it worked. I didn't notice until that point. But it definitely had multiple chances to expire the cache refresh. Pat, that isn't an option in this scenario.